# Dynamically update rails form textarea based on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a table called **Email_Template**. It contains **two columns: template_name and template_body**.

I also have a **form** in which **user selects template_name in dropdown** (coming from database column). In the same form, based on template_name selection, the **textarea should display corresponding “template_body**” content coming from the same database table. Please tell me how to do this.

My Form

```
<%= form_for :email_form, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, url: candidates_send_email_path do |f| %>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :template_name, "Template" %>
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <%= select_tag "template_name", options_from_collection_for_select(Email_Template.all, "id", "id") %>
      </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :template_body, "Template Body" %>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= f.text_area :email_content, rows: 7 %><br/>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class=text-right>
   <%= f.button class: "btn btn-primary btn-modal" do %>
     SEND EMAIL <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
   <% end %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
post '/template_body_finder/:template_id' => 'search#find_template'
```

search_controller.rb

```
def find_template
    @email_template = Email_Template.find(params[:template_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

search.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#template_id', (evt) ->
    template_id = $(this).val()
    window.alert(template_id)
    curr_url = "/template_body_finder/" + template_id
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: curr_url,
          data: {'template_id': template_id},
          success: ( data, status, xhr ) -> })
```

find_template.js.erb

```
$(“#email_content”).val= <%= @email_template.template_body %>
;
```

Comment: try this in your find_template.js.erb $(“#email_content”).val(<%= @email_template.template_body %>);

Comment: @StephenM: tried this, but I think my ajax call is not working. In find_template.js.erb, even if I am putting window.alert, nothing is coming up. So, the call to controller is not happening. Any ideas on this?

Comment: email_templates is your model right. Then change this `Email_Template.find(params[:template_id])` to `EmailTemplate.find(params[:template_id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this:-

1- your form

```
<%= form_for :email_form, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, url: candidates_send_email_path_path do |f| %>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :template_name, "Template" %>
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <%= select_tag "template_name", options_from_collection_for_select(Email_Template.all, "id", "id") %>
      </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :template_body, "Template Body" %>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= f.text_area :email_content, rows: 7 %><br/>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class=text-right>
   <%= f.button class: "btn btn-primary btn-modal" do %>
     SEND EMAIL <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
   <% end %>
 </div>

<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#template_name').on('change', function(){
        var template_id = $(this).val();
        // alert(template_id);
        // ajax request
    $.ajax({
      url: "/template_body_finder",
      type: "GET",
      data : {
        template_id: template_id
      },
      dataType: "script",
    });
    })
</script>
```

2- change your url:

```
get '/template_body_finder' => 'search#find_template'
```

3- in controller -

```
def find_template
    @email_template = Email_Template.find(params[:template_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

4- in your find_template.js.erb file it should like this-

```
$('#email_form_email_content').val("<%=@email_template.template_body%>");
```

this works for me, if you have any doubt you can ask in comments.
thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anand. while your method works for all cases, it fails when template_body has text followed by "ENTER". e.g. #<Email_Template id: 3, template_name: "Product Manager 2", template_body: "Hey its awesome!\r\n\r\nGood", created_at: "2017-10-05 11:56:21", updated_at: "2017-10-12 18:06:35">.....In that case nothing is happening on changing the dropdown.

Comment: can you try this: in `find_template.js.erb`  `$('#email_form_email_content').val("<%=@email_template.template_body.html_safe%>");`